# Xamarin iOS Crash on Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

We are use Xamarin forms local notifications on our app. with the below line in the code it causes the app the crash

`UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RemovePendingNotificationRequests(requests);`

even tho the line should only be run on iOS devices. this is done with the following;

`

```
                            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == "Android")
                            {


                            }
                            else
                            {
                                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RemovePendingNotificationRequests(requests);
                            }
```

`

the below error is given with the UNUserNotificationsCenter in the code

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' or one of its dependencies.`

anyone any ideas??

We have tried completely reimplementing the local notifications, clean and clearing bin/obj. updated both machine and vs to the latest version, updated frameworks.

built on VS Mac 2022 17.3.6
android framework 13.0.0.0

Comment: that code shouldn't even compile.  You are using an iOS API that doesn't exist in Android.

Comment: its within a shared file and complies but it complies fine

Comment: you need to use #if to conditionally compile per platform

Comment: it is within an if as shown above... but unless you comment out the iOS code it will crash with the iOS error

Comment: `if` is evaluated at **runtime**.  An `#if` is a compiler directive that is evaluated at compile

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing#benefits-1

Comment: the #if wasn't compatible seemingly, found a fix by creating an interface for each platform and running the code behind that.

Comment: You can try to move the namespace of the ios method into the `#if`.